# how can I perform segue with another view only when email was sent?

Tags: email, swift3

For some reason this code doesn't work it gives off the error:"Warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy". But i don't understand how to fix this. Here is my code.

```
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case .saved:
        print("Mail saved")
    case .sent:
        print("Mail sent")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AllList", sender: self)
        AllListOfViolations.violationType.append("\(LocationAndTimeData.getSystemDate())")
    case .failed:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "nil")")
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is before performing segue you need to dismiss the `MFMailComposeViewController`, so try to segue in the completion block of `dismiss` on basis of some condition. Also if you are accessing `AllListOfViolations.violationType` in `prepareForSegue` then append object in array before calling `performSegue`.

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    var needToSegue = false
    switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case .saved:
        print("Mail saved")
    case .sent:
        needToSegue = true
        print("Mail sent")
    case .failed:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "nil")")
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
        if needToSegue {
            AllListOfViolations.violationType.append("\(LocationAndTimeData.getSystemDate())")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AllList", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```